How to search for value in object[,] using LINQ
I have a large matrix that represents tabular data, and I need to find the row where a specific value exists in the first column. Here is a simplified version that give the same compile-time error, CS1503, "cannot convert from 'object[,]' to '?[]'"
object[,] mx = new object[,]{{"ABC",123}};
var f = Array.Find<>(mx, x => ((string)x[0]).Equals("ABC"));

I suppose I could iterate, but there must be a more elegant way.
I tried different LINQ queries, but not get any to compile.
Kevin

Why aren't you using a dictionary?

@jdweng, This matrix is the output from another library I'm using, and  as I stated above, this example is a simplified version so we can focus on the problem to solved instead of why I'm not using a dictionary.

In a 2-dimensional array, you are pretty much required to do 2-dimensional iteration. Other than code clarity (and using someone else's tested code) LINQ doesn't buy you much more than doing the iterations yourself. If you want, you could write a LINQ-style extension function on T[,] that takes Func<T,bool> and returns either a T (if it stops on the first match) or an IEnumerable<T>

@KevinS.Miller If you're using a library that's providing you malformed data (which I would argue this is), or data in an inappropriate format, it's typically best to immediately transform it into a more suitable structure.  In this case that would likely be a list of objects, a dictionary, or something.  You haven't made it clear what it should be, but what it is isn't really suitable to any application basically anywhere.  Honestly I'd be pretty suspicious of any library that would produce data like this (either it's a bad library or you're using it wrong).

Trying to ignore your actual problem and attempt to treat a symptom is just going to give you more problems.

Array.Find does not search 2D arrays. Please read the docs.

To create an array of arrays, that will work with Array.Find(), try object[][] mx = new object[][]{new object[]{"ABC",123}};.  Better would be to map the properties to a named class (or even an anonymous class) and create an array of that class. However, if you are going to map the data to a collection of class instances and need to perform multiple lookups, you might as well map it all to a dictionary at that point to support efficient lookups.

@Servy, My question is an academic one, I was hoping to find an elegant, one-line solution using LINQ in the same way you can use LINQ to find a property value in an object in an array.  I as dr.null says above, Find is only for 1d arrays.

@KevinS.Miller So is specifically created for practical programming problems.  If this is a situation you're actually in then you're attempting to solve it in a way that makes your problem worse and you need to correct the actual underlying problem, which is that your data is severely malformed and that will make all usage of it problematic until you fix it.  Treating the symptoms of your problem and not the underlying cause causes more problems.

You could write a LINQ-style extension method, something like
[Test]
public void FindRowTest()
{
    object[,] mx = new object[,] { { "A", 1 }, { "B", 2 } , { "C", 3 } };
    Assert.AreEqual((1, 0), FindCellIndex(mx, v => v .Equals("B")));
}

public static (int Row, int Column)? FindCellIndex<T>(T[,] array, Func<T, bool> condition )
{
    var rows = array.GetLength(0);
    var cols = array.GetLength(1);
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            if (condition(array[r, c]))
            {
                return ( r, c );
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

LINQ is not really elegant at stuff like finding indices, and both the multidimensionallity and object further works against you. So you are unlikely to completely escape loops.
